# UML Class Diagram: Abstract or Interface?

Tags: interfaces, uml, class-diagram, abstract-class

I am modeling a class diagram and have spotted an opportunity to simplify it slightly. What I want to know is, would this it be better to implement an abstract class or an interface?

The scenario is this, I have the classes:

- Artist
- Genre
- Album
- Song

All of which share the methods getName, setName, and getCount (playcount that is). Would it be best to create an abstract 'Music' class with the aforementioned abstract methods, or should I create an interface, since the classes that implement the interface have to include all of the interface's methods (I think, correct me if I'm wrong).

I hope I've given enough detail, please ask questions if I haven't.

Thanks!

Comment: It is better to use interface and refer this site for more information:http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Interfaces+and+Abstract+Classes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an abstract class.

Generally speaking, a song can consist of a Title / Artist / Album / Genre. All of those are just a string of data which can be handled the same way.
By using an abstract class you don't have to write mentioned "getName", "setName" and "getCount" more than once, which sounds pretty neat.

Using an interface would just tell you that the functions should exist in each class, but you'd still have to write them separately. However, if you come up with methods they all have in common, but which work differently for each class, I suppose an interface would make more sense.

What bugs me though is that you want them to be classes. For example, since you would want an album to have it's own "Times played", you'd have to make sure that there's only one instance of that specific album. Each time a new song is added, you'd either have to search through all existing classes with that name and set a pointer or something similar to the already existing one.

Then again, the good part about using an album as an instance of a class, is that it's possible to have several albums with the same "name" without counting them as the same album. Err.. anyways, my mind has drifted away and this is not really related to the question.

Comment: Thanks! That's a very useful and concise answer, just what I was after! :D

Answer (score 0):

I would use interfaces instead.
From my experience, there are 2 reasons for this:

- Only use (abstract) class at the root of the diagram when you are so confident that sub-classes are very very similar
- Unless you are very fluent in the area, will you need to make lot of modifications to not just your code but even your design too. This is when interfaces will be much more suitable, changing around the interface inheritance tree is much less disruptive than dealing with abstract classes.

Think about the Venn diagram and two not-equal sets of functionalities. A and B. In java you can only extend one abstract class, which one should you choose?
If you choose A, some time in the future, the need arises that you didn't anticipate so B inflates to be bigger than A. You will need to change to B and then something that you didn't anticipated arises and you change back to A.

Is it better to just use interfaces and then when the code base is stable, you refactor and common up the same functionalities in an abstract class.
Interfaces are much more agile and suitable for those constant changes. Of course if you already know way too well what will be anticipated, then by all means go with abstract classes.